# Describe LAST item of array in json schema?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I use JSON Schema to describe my data structure

My data contains specific arrays of the following structure:

```
{
    "string1",
    "string2",
    ...
    "stringN",
    {
       "object": "as",
       "last": "item"
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how to describe this in json schema (especially the thing "last item is an object")

If I knew the number of string items, ["prefixItems"](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#id7) would do the thing (but there could be any number of them).

If the object was the first (not last) item, "prefixItems" together with ["items"](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#id8) would work.

If is use ["contains"](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#id10), it only checks the object is somewhere in my array, not checking it is the last item.

Seems that I need something like "reversePrefixItems", if such option existed - but it doesn't exists.

So, what is a proper way to describe the last item of an array? (and optionally all the preceding ones - knowing their type but not their total count)

Answer (score 1):

there has been discussion of a proposed keyword `postfixItems` but it has not yet made it into the spec. I don't think there is a way to do this currently.

Comment: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/1060